# Multiple charts not showing on Chart TableLayoutPanel in Winforms Application

Tags: winforms, mschart, tablelayoutpanel

I am adding Multiple rows on Table Layout Panel. I am using 2 Columns.I am adding dynamically Charts on every rows.

I want to show 500 charts on this panel means there is a requirement of 250 rows.

My code is doing exactly what I want. but It shows me only 162 Charts, others are not showing however I can see the scrollbar. when I am scrolling a panel It shows me blank and last two 
charts are truncated.

I am also using download charts in png format. When I am downloading from the Panel.controls, It allows me downloading.

I thought there might be a printing issue. I have also tried with `Panel.ResumeLayout();`

can any body solve this ?